# Consecutive read/write threads synchronization in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization, readerwriterlock

I'm trying to implement the Reader/Writer lock mechanism to control the synchronization of 3 threads each of which is executed 4 times based on random draw of dice. For example, for thread i, random.randint(1, 6) is called and if the output is even, thread i is read, if odd, thread i is write. [Here](https://majid.info/blog/a-reader-writer-lock-for-python/) I found a general implementation of the reader/writer lock, but I wasn't successful in doing these 4 operations for the 3 threads. here is parts of the original code along with my additions at the end:

```
import threading
import time, random
class RWLock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rwlock = 0
        self.writers_waiting = 0
        self.monitor = threading.Lock()
        self.readers_ok = threading.Condition(self.monitor)
        self.writers_ok = threading.Condition(self.monitor)
    def acquire_read(self):
        self.monitor.acquire()
        while self.rwlock < 0 or self.writers_waiting:
            self.readers_ok.wait()
        self.rwlock += 1
        self.monitor.release()
    def acquire_write(self):
        self.monitor.acquire()
        while self.rwlock != 0:
            self.writers_waiting += 1
            self.writers_ok.wait()
            self.writers_waiting -= 1
        self.rwlock = -1
        self.monitor.release()
    def release(self):
        self.monitor.acquire()
        if self.rwlock < 0:
            self.rwlock = 0
        else:
            self.rwlock -= 1
        wake_writers = self.writers_waiting and self.rwlock == 0
        wake_readers = self.writers_waiting == 0
        self.monitor.release()
        if wake_writers:
            self.writers_ok.acquire()
            self.writers_ok.notify()
            self.writers_ok.release()
        elif wake_readers:
            self.readers_ok.acquire()
            self.readers_ok.notifyAll()
            self.readers_ok.release()

rwl = RWLock()

class Reader(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        print "Thread " + str(threading.active_count()) + " is now ready for reading shard location\n"
        rwl.acquire_read()
        time.sleep(5)
        print "Thread " + str(threading.active_count()) + " now has finished reading shard location\n"
        rwl.release()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        self._is_running = False

class Writer(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        print "Thread " + str(threading.active_count()) + " is now ready to write to shard location\n"
        rwl.acquire_write()
        time.sleep(5)
        print "Thread " + str(threading.active_count()) + " now has finished writing to shard location\n"
        rwl.release()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        self._is_running = False

alpha = list("ABC")
d = {i: 4 for i in alpha}

def execute(thread):
    global d
    diceDraw = random.randint(1, 6)
    if diceDraw % 2 == 0:
        thread = Reader()
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        thread = Writer()
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(1)

while sum(d.values()) > 0:
    for i in d.keys():
        if i:
            execute(i)
            d[i] -= 1
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you use [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), which is already synchronized?

Comment: excuse my noob(ness) but how exactly this is gonna work with the original code?

Comment: I am suggesting an alternative. Moreover, this is a problem which is already solved, so we don't have to reinvent the wheel :-) Producers will push to the queue and the consumers will just pop from the queue. Enqueuing and dequeing process is completely synchronized. So, if that is all what you are trying to do, then you should consider using it.

Comment: in the piece of code I added, I just created a list of three letters ['A', 'B', 'C'] to be assigned to the Reader/Writer lock ... are you suggesting a queue instead?

Comment: Ya, let the producer add the data to the queue, I mean, instead of storing it in the list, use a `queue.Queue`.